# Como faço para não mapear uma Classe com o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou fazendo meu primeiro sistema (C# ASP MVC 5) com o Entity Framework e Migrations.

Tenho minhas classes que foram mapeadas corretamente e migradas para o Banco de Dados que é SQL Server 2012.

Mas a questão é como eu posso criar uma classe que não seja mapeada pelo EF e Migrations?

Tenho uma classe de Certificados conforme abaixo:

Nesta classe que criar um campo StatusCertificado, para isso pensei em criar uma classe para que seja um tipo de dados enum, mas o EF insiste em criar essa classe/tabela no meu banco de dados. Este Enum apenas teria os valores (Ativo, Inativo, Vencido).

Penso então que eu não preciso criar uma tabela fisica no banco.

Qual a melhor forma de eu fazer isso? Agradeço antecipadamente.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ControleGCD.Models
{
    public class Certificado
    {

        [Key]
        public int CertificadoId { get; set; }

        public string CertificadoChave { get; set; }

        public string CertificadoDescricao { get; set; }

        public decimal CertificadoPreco { get; set; }

        public DateTime CertificadoDtCompra { get; set; }

        public DateTime CertificadoDtVencimento { get; set; }

        public DateTime CertificadoDtCadastro { get; set; }

       **public DateTime CertificadoStatus{ get; set; }**

    }
}
```

Comment: "seja um tipo de dados enum", porque não criar um enum?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a *DataAnnotation* [`[NotMapped]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_4)

```
namespace ControleGCD.Models
{
    public class Certificado
    {
        //...
        public DateTime CertificadoDtCadastro { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime CertificadoStatus{ get; set; }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui perfeitamente, criei uma nova classe Enum (StatusCertificado )e na minha classe ja existente (certificados) criei uma propriedade do tipo StatusCertificado. Deu certinho. Obrigado pela ajuda.